# Check, then set, a global variable in Python

Tags: python

I have python function that needs to set a global variable on it's first run and modify it on other runs
I've tried implementing this as follows:

```
def foo():
    if 'some_var' in globals():
        some_var = some_var + 1
    else:
        global some_var
        some_var = 0
```

However, I get a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: name 'some_var' is used prior to global declaration
```

Why is this? How do I implement this functionality correctly?

Comment: Move "global some_var" to the beginning of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moving global `some_var` to the top of the function should be fine:

```
def foo():
    global some_var
    if 'some_var' in globals():
        some_var = some_var + 1
    else:
        some_var = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see
[name 'times' is used prior to global declaration - But IT IS declared!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105611/name-times-is-used-prior-to-global-declaration-but-it-is-declared)

The correct code would be:

```py
def foo():
    if 'some_var' not in globals():
        global some_var 
        some_var=0
    else:
        some_var+=1
```

Comment: missing indents